# Why does onMouseOver disappear in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have an interesting phenomenon in my react code; I add some mouseevent functions like below :

```
              <div
            className="margin-mini"
            onMouseOver={() => {
              console.log(1);
            }}
            onMouseOut={() => {
              console.log(2);
            }}
            onMouseEnter={() => {
              console.log(3);
            }}
            onMouseLeave={() => {
              console.log(4);
            }}
          >
            Add2
          </div>
```

.. and the result of this is a simple

```
<div class="margin-mini">Add2</div>
```

Any idea why the rest disappears / stripped out ? As far as I can see, there are no errors on the nodejs compile or the browser console.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

React binds event listeners with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

It doesn't generate `on*` attributes, which are problematic in general and really don't play well with variable scoping for dynamic functions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Quentin ! Yet, it does not explain why the attributes disappear. I tried the same code on a <button> and it works totally fine.

Comment: They disappear because they are not converted to HTML attributes. They use `addEventListener`. They aren't for button elements either (maybe you typed `onclick` there instead of `onClick`).